# Decimals round off only when report is run live

Tags: crystal-reports, decimal, crosstab

My crosstab displays percentages with two decimal points when run locally. Run from Live in Crystal Report Viewer, the values are rounded to the nearest integer. How can I force the decimals to show?

[image]

---

**Run *locally* from Crystal Reports:**

[image]

---

**Run from Crystal Report Viewer *Live:***

[image]

Comment: One option I can think is, Since you are facing problem with display only, Convert the final result to String and then view on Crystal Report Viewer. This should help you

Comment: Already tried that - it just returns `5.00%`, `53.00%`, `34.00%`...

Comment: In that case separate the part before and after decimal and then append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I needed to perform the calculation manually:

I created a running total called *MyDistinctCount* to get the total number of entries, 132. Then I duplicated the first row of the CrossTab (**Total:** | **7** | **71** | **46**...) and altered the Display Text field to use this formula:

```
ToText( ToNumber(CurrentFieldValue)/{#MyDistinctCount} * 100 ) + "%"
```

[image]